# Как заменить метод onResume при помощи xposed

Tags: java, android, методы, framework, hook

Хочу этот код

```
@Override protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(this, "text",0).show();
}
```

Заменить на этот

```
@Override protected void onResume(){
     super.onResume();
}

findAndHookMethod(myPackageName+".MainActivity", lpparam.classLoader, "onResume", new XC_MethodHook() {
    @Override
    protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
        param.setResult(null);
    }
}
```

Часто бывает, что много чего написано в этом методе, поэтому нужно удалить все из метода onResume и сделать его пустым. Ни как не получается это сделать либо ничего не происходит, либо ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object obj = XposedHelpers.callMethod(param.thisObject, "onKeyDown");//костыль чтобы не вызывался стандартный метод onResume
param.setResult(obj);
```

такой способ работает.
Полезно кстати писать на форумы, стоит написать как тут же сам находишь ответ